# In the Esaki diode, how do physicists measure/estimate the velocity of a would-be-tunneling electron?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, semiconductor-physics, quantum-tunneling

Layman's explanation, please. Let's consider an Esaki diode.

How do physicists measure/obtain the velocity of a would-be-tunneling electron in order to justify the claim that *the potential barrier is higher in energy in comparison with the tunneling electron*?

And, a follow-up question: **how can one be certain that the electron (on the other side of the barrier) is "the same" electron whose velocity one have measured before the quantum tunneling**?

Comment: that fellow helped make japan the major innovator it became in the 1960s. we had so little after the war.

Answer (score 0):

This is a long comment.

At the level of diodes  one is in the calculational range of quantum mechanics, the  *measuring the velocity of a  single  electron* within the diode has no meaning. In quantum mechanics one deals with probabilities, which means the measurable quantities come from the accumulation of many events with the exact boundary conditions .

Now at the level of the diode, the velocities of the electrons are calculated from knowing the interactions they come from

> [Tunnel diodes have a heavily doped positive-to-negative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tunnel_diode) (P-N) junction that is about 10 nm (100 Å) wide. The heavy doping results in a broken band gap, where conduction band electron states on the N-side are more or less aligned with valence band hole states on the P-side. They are usually made from germanium, but can also be made from gallium arsenide and silicon materials.

So there is no meaning to the *"the same" electron whose velocity one have measured*. It is all a matter of accumulating statistics biased with the quantum mechanical states.

See this for the t[unneling effect.](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/barr.html)

Comment: If measuring the velocity of a single electron within the diode has no meaning, then how can one meaningfully and reasonably hold that the electron actually crosses the PN-junction "without having sufficient energy to do so"?

Comment: It is the statistical accumulation/distribution of the solid composing the diode, with enough energy to tunnel. think how large avogadro's number is, large, see how many atoms are in 6 grams of diamond here  https://www.guidechem.com/question/how-many-atoms-of-carbon-are-i-id32173.html

Comment: I don't have idea what is your point. Again, tunneling is phenomenon where a particle is able to penetrate through a potential energy barrier which is higher in energy than the particle's kinetic energy. If obtaining the velocity of an electron within the diode has no meaning, then how can we claim meaningfully that what we observe within the diode is actually QUANTUM TUNNELING of electrons?

Comment: Also, "the velocities of the electrons are calculated from knowing the interactions they come from"  What do you mean? Could you, please, elaborate more.

Comment: Let me put the question in other words: at the level of the diode, how do one know that the "tunneling" electron's kinetic energy is lower than the barrier's energy?

Comment: see this on p n junctions  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P%E2%80%93n_junction.  Can you understand it? It is talking of currents of electrons moving over the junction to the holes, not of individual electrons energy. The motion has a distribution in velocities, and in the particular junction you are asking about, tunneling effects, as in the link I give in the answer, happen to individual electrons of the appropriate energy, but the effect is collective, no individual electron is measured in the diode. The distributions fit the mathematical predictions.

Comment: a question and answer site is not one that can give a course in basic quantum physics .